# how to copy one content to another tag content using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a tag :

```
<footnote xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"><para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para></footnote>
```

I want to create new tag '`ftnote`' with same attributes and contents from above '`footnote`' tag. it should be like :

```
<ftnote xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"><para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para></ftnote>
```

can someone give any solution for this

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First template to copy the xml nodes as is.. second one to change the element name:
Note: your XML input is buggy.. namespace declaration for "aid" prefix is missing.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="footnote">
    <ftnote>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </ftnote>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```